# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerMovement.activeMoveSpeed'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Just picked up Unity about a week ago, I have really been struggling to fix this problem and referencing overall, I'm well aware that I need to read and watch more tutorials, I just want to get this fixed so I can continue working on my game.

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `PlayerMovement.activeMoveSpeed`

The first problem was referencing the other Game Object and script, I not sure if its completely fixed now but
at least that not the error that its giving me anymore, I've tried doing what this link says
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1119537/help-how-do-i-referenceaccess-another-script-in-un.html
but as you might see it hasn't worked out, every single time I get the compile errors fixed the script doesn't work because the object reference is not set to an instance of an object, any help would be extremely appreciated (the script I'm trying to reference will be at the end)
Thanks

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShieldAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject shield;
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    private Camera mainCam;
    public bool isDashing;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    GameObject Player;
    PlayerMovement playerMovement;
    Shooting shooting;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("EnemyMelee");
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy2");

        mainCam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mousePos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        Vector3 rotation = mousePos - transform.position;

        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(rotation.y, rotation.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && playerMovement.dashCoolCounter <= 0 && playerMovement.dashCounter <= 0)
        {
            isDashing = true;
            Instantiate(shield, shooting.bulletTransform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            if (PlayerMovement.activeMoveSpeed == 5)
            {
                DestroyShield();
                isDashing = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void DestroyShield()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float moveSpeed;
   public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
   private Vector2 moveInput;

   public float activeMoveSpeed;
   public float dashSpeed;

   public float dashLength = 0.5f, dashCooldown = 1f;

   public float dashCounter;
   public float dashCoolCounter;

   [SerializeField] private TrailRenderer tr;

   //Start is called before the first frame update
   void Start()
   {
      activeMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
   }

   //Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {

      if(dashCounter > 0)
      {
         tr.emitting = true;
      }

      if(dashCounter < 0)
      {
         tr.emitting = false;
      }

      moveInput.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
      moveInput.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

      moveInput.Normalize();

      rb2d.velocity = moveInput * activeMoveSpeed; 

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
      {

         if (dashCoolCounter <=0 && dashCounter <=0)
         {
            activeMoveSpeed = dashSpeed;
            dashCounter = dashLength;
         }

      }

      if (dashCounter > 0)
      {
         dashCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

         if (dashCounter <= 0)
         {
            activeMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
            dashCoolCounter = dashCooldown;
         }
      }

      if (dashCoolCounter > 0)
      {
         dashCoolCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Don't know much about unity but based on the error message, you can only access the `activeMoveSpeed` from an object of `PlayerMovement`.  Seems like you are trying to access it with just the class name `PlayerMovement` which is only works for static classes and static methods, properties and fields.  So instantiate an object from `PlayerMovement` first and use that object to access `activeMoveSpeed`.  Also the .NET naming convention is not followed but considering you are working with Unity, it may be based on a different convention.

Answer (score 0):

You are using class name `PlayerMovement.activeMoveSpeed` instead of object name `playerMovement.activeMoveSpeed` in this part of code:

```
if (PlayerMovement.activeMoveSpeed == 5)
{
    DestroyShield();
    isDashing = false;
}
```

Also I cannot see `playerMovement` variable initialization in the `ShieldAttack` script. You need to mark it with the `[SerializeField]` attribute or make it public to be able to assign it in the inspector. Or initialize it in your `Start()` method along with the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a variable, you do `<type> <name>`, where `<type>` is the kind of thing you want to create and `<name>` is how you want to reference the *instance* you created.

We as programmers are generally lazy, so if we wanted to create a pineapple we would create an instance of the `Pineapple` class. What do we call it? Typically just `pineapple`, and then you wind up with code like

```
Pineapple pineapple;
```

The first term means you're wanting to create a `Pineapple`, and the second term means you're going to refer to that *instance* as `pineapple`. Note the capitalization differences there.

The issue with your code is that you've created an *instance* of `PlayerMovement`:

```
PlayerMovement playerMovement;
```

but when you're trying to use the *instance* in your code, you are using the **class** name `PlayerMovement` and not the **instance** name `playerMovement`. Again, note the capitalization difference.

The particular line that you've got:

```
if (PlayerMovement.activeMoveSpeed == 5)
```

should instead be:

```
if (playerMovement.activeMoveSpeed == 5)
```

to refer to the *instance* and not the *class*.

It *is* possible to have things that are common to **all** instances of a class. Those are *static* items and you would access them by referencing the class name instead of the instance name.

The error message you got:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property PlayerMovement.activeMoveSpeed

was telling you that you were trying to access a part of the **class**, but it wasn't static, so you needed to reference the object (instance).